# How can I return a string from an async operation?

Tags: c#, file-io, asynchronous

I'm using [PCLStorage](http://pclstorage.codeplex.com/wikipage?referringTitle=Documentation) and need a way to read a file. I'm going to use JSON for serialization, so I just need to read the saved content from the file:

```
        public async string ReadFromFile(string filename)
        {
            IFolder rootFolder = FileSystem.Current.LocalStorage;
            IFolder folder = await rootFolder.CreateFolderAsync("MySubFolder", CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);
            IFile file = await folder.GetFileAsync(filename);
            string content = await file.ReadAllTextAsync();

            return content;
        }
```

But I cant return string, it has to be void, Task or Task.

Is there a easy way I can Return string from this method? maybe by invoking another method?

Comment: You can return a string like this public async Task<string> YourAsyncMethod() {return "test";}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to return a `Task<string>`, like this:

```
public async Task<string> ReadFromFile(string filename)
{
    IFolder rootFolder = FileSystem.Current.LocalStorage;
    IFolder folder = await rootFolder.CreateFolderAsync("MySubFolder", 
        CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);
    IFile file = await folder.GetFileAsync(filename);
    string content = await file.ReadAllTextAsync();

    return content;
}
```

Comment: oh, it was not harder... but do I have to await this method when I use it?

Comment: @Jason94 Yep. Or you could save the `Task<string>`, do some work, and then await it.